# WSO2 AS JDNI lookup

Tags: datasource, jndi, wso2

In WSO2 AS 5.0.1 I deploy a webapp which should use a datasource.
I can configure the datasource in tomcat-server.xml or any other place in the WAR, but is it possible to use a datasource that is configured in the Carbon Management Console through JNDI?

Steps taken:

1. Configure datasource in Management Console, export it as JNDI as jdbc/platform
2. ResourceLink in META-INF/context.xml to link the global resource:

   < ResourceLink name="jdbc/platform" global="jdbc/platform" type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
3. Reference the resource in web.xml

   < resource-ref>
       < res-ref-name>jdbc/platform
       < res-type>javax.sql.DataSource
       < res-auth>Application

However trying to lookup jdbc/platform or java:comp/env/jdbc/platform does not resolve into an object. The lookup files with messages like: Name [java:jdbc/platform] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [java:jdbc]. or, when using comp/env as prefix it will complain that 'comp' is not available.

Is this kind of configuration supported by WSO2 Carbon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this is not supported see https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-13908.

Comment: Thanks! Will keep an eye on that ticket as this seems a valuable feature

Comment: Now this problem is solved.see http://www.mail-archive.com/dev@wso2.org/msg12522.html.With next release it will be available.If you want it now patch your settup with the patch in that mail.

Answer (score 0):

This feature will work on AS 5.1.0 version which planed to release very soon.